# How to rotate single row to key-value table in SSRS 2012?

Tags: reporting-services, ssrs-2012

Using SSRS 2012 with SQL Server 2012. I have a result set in SQL Server 2012 which has the following fields as headers:

```
sumDeposits,
sumWithdrawals,
sumFees,
etc
```

This has been mapped to a Dataset in SSRS.

I would like a SSRS table or matrix where I can have the column header as column one and the data row (there is only one row in the result set) as column two in a table. Is this possible? Been struggling with it.

I should add that the way I am doing it now is to drag a Field from the Dataset onto the SSRS page, and then put a text box next to it. The number of fields is growing so I'd rather have a table.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It sounds like you want to *unpivot* the data from columns into rows. If that is the case, then you should be able to use the [UNPIVOT](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms177410%28v=sql.105%29.aspx) function in SQL.

The basic structure of the query will be:

```
select col, value
from yourtable
unpivot
(
  value
  for col in (sumDeposits, sumWithdrawals, sumFees) -- your columns here
)unpiv;
```

If you have data that is not the same datatype, then you will have to convert the data for all columns to be the same type:

```
select col, value
from 
(
  select sumDeposits, 
    cast(sumWithdrawals as numeric(10, 2)) sumWithdrawals, 
    sumFees
  from yourtable
) d
unpivot
(
  value
  for col in (sumDeposits, sumWithdrawals, sumFees)
) unpiv;
```

This type of query is exactly the same as using a `UNION ALL` with multiple calls to the same table:

```
select 'sumDeposits' col, sumDeposits as value
from yourtable
union all
select 'sumWithdrawals' col, sumWithdrawals as value
from yourtable
union all
select 'sumFees' col, sumFees as value
from yourtable
```